# Can I use external methods as route decorators in Python/Flask?

Tags: python, flask

My main app file is currently a series of method definitions, each attached to a route. I've got 3 distinct parts to my app (main, admin, api). I'm trying to split out methods into external files for better maintenance but I like Flask's simplicity in using route decorators for my application's URLs.

One of my routes currently looks like this:

```
# index.py
@application.route('/api/galleries')
def get_galleries():
    galleries = {
        "galleries": # get gallery objects here
    }
    return json.dumps(galleries)
```

But I'd like to extract the get_galleries method into a file containing methods for my API:

```
import api
@application.route('/api/galleries')
api.get_galleries():
```

The problem is that when I do that I get an error. Is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like stated in the other comment, you can call `app.route('/')(api.view_home())` or use Flask's `app.add_url_rule()` http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule

Flask's `@app.route()` code:

```
def route(self, rule, **options):
    def decorator(f):
        endpoint = options.pop('endpoint', None)
        self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
        return f
    return decorator
```

You can do the following:

```
## urls.py

from application import app, views

app.add_url_rule('/', 'home', view_func=views.home)
app.add_url_rule('/user/<username>', 'user', view_func=views.user)
```

And then:

```
## views.py

from flask import request, render_template, flash, url_for, redirect

def home():
    render_template('home.html')

def user(username):
    return render_template('user.html', username=username)
```

Is the method I use for breaking things down. Define all your `urls` in it's own file and then `import urls` in your `__init__.py` that runs `app.run()`

In your case:

```
|-- app/
|-- __init__.py (where app/application is created and ran)
|-- api/
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- views.py
```

api/urls.py

```
from application import app

import api.views

app.add_url_rule('/call/<call>', 'call', view_func=api.views.call)
```

api/views.py

```
from flask import render_template

def call(call):
    # do api call code.
```

Answer (score 1):

A decorator is just a special function.

```
routed_galleries = application.route('/api/galleries')(api.get_galleries)
```

And in fact, depending on what the decorator does you may not need to keep the result around at all.

```
application.route('/api/galleries')(api.get_galleries)
```

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are just functions, so you can just do:

```
import api
api.get_galleries = application.route(api.get_galleries, '/api/galleries')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can decorate a method in that way. But I suppose instead of using the decorator the normal way, you could create a callback to decorate it manually.

```
def wrap_api(cls, rt):
  return application.route(rt)(cls)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
import api
galleries = wrap_api(api.get_galleries(), '/api/galleries')
```

Comment: This is pretty much doing the same thing that `flask.add_url_rule()` does. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule

Comment: You're right. Certainly best to use the API in this case (in my opinion).