# Zappa not packaging nested source directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, zappa

I have a python application that I am trying to deploy with zappa. The root level of my directory has the application and a directory named **helper**. The structure looks like this:

```
|-app.py
|-zappa_settings.json
|-helper
   |-api.py
   |-__init.py__
```

Within the helper directory there is an **api.py** file that is referenced in my **app.py** like so

```
from helper import api
```

When I run the command to package and deploy using `zappa deploy dev` it will not bundle the **helper** directory in the deployment, only the root level application directory. How do you tell zappa to include all sub-directories when packaging and deploying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After struggling with this myself, I realized that the idea is to package up your other code, install it in your virtual environment, and have app.py just be a driver that calls your other functions.

Here's a concrete minimum example using Flask. First, let's extend your example with one more file, `setup.py`:

```
|-app.py
|-zappa_settings.json
|-setup.py
|-helper
   |-api.py
   |-__init.py__
```

`__init__.py` is empty. The rest of the files are as follows:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='helper',
    packages=['helper'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=['flask']
)


# app.py    
from helper import api
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return api.index()


# helper/api.py
def index():
    return "This is the index content"


# zappa_settings.json
{
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "app.app",
        "s3_bucket": "my_bucket"
    }
}
```

Now you `pip install -e .` while in your virtual environment. If you now run `app.py` using Flask and go `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`, you'll see that you get `This is the index content`. And if you `deploy` using Zappa, you'll see that your API endpoint does the same thing.

Comment: What I have not figured out how to do is to pass the `app` context to `api.py` so that I can do the routing without losing those beautiful decorators. If you can live without decorators, you can do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129573/can-i-use-external-methods-as-route-decorators-in-python-flask